# Android - Sending pdf

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send a .pdf file to Google Cloud print, using Google Docs as printer.
Google docs get the document, but it appears empty, do somebody know the possible problem?

For send the pdf, I read it as an string and:

```
str = URLEncoder.encode(pdf);
OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
out.write(str.getBytes());
out.close();
```

I send more things, I only copy here a part

(Fixed a error, out.getBytes() -> str.getBytes())

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are sending the URL of pdf, whereas the server expects a pdf file. You should read the pdf file, and send its content and not its url.

How you can read a binary file is explained here:

http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter09/fileBinaryIO.html

Just read the file and then write its contents to `OutputStream`.

Comment: mmm, i read the file, not use the link, but i read it as text, i will try reading as binary. Thanks you

Comment: I have tried it, but it stills fail, the problem is that i encode the content of the pdf, and send it, but Google Docs receive other data.     
Example: "xœuÎ=Â0à=¿âfÁx—4ÍB Õvp+ÄÍM°‹ßKãT‘ÀñÂ" turns into "xu=0=fx4Bvp+MKT"with characters that cant be copied to here between its.
I think it must be a codification problem, but i have tried all :S

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
out.write(out.getBytes());
```

be instead

```
out.write(str.getBytes());
```

or something like that?